# Reading and writing from a csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

```
Structure TownType
    Dim Name As String
    Dim County As String
    Dim Population As Integer
    Dim Area As Integer
End Structure

Sub Main()
    Dim TownList As TownType
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim NumberOfRecords As Integer
    FileName = "N:\2_7_towns(2).csv"

    FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(TownList))
    NumberOfRecords = LOF(1) / Len(TownList)
    Console.WriteLine(NumberOfRecords)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

There are only 12 records in the file but this returns a value of 24 for number of records. How do I fix this?

Contents of csv file:

```
Town, County,Pop, Area
Berwick-upon-tweed, Nothumberland,12870,468
Bideford, devon,16262,430
Bognor Regis, West Sussex,62141,1635
Bridlington, East Yorkshire,33589,791
Bridport, Dorset,12977,425
Cleethorpes, Lincolnshire,31853,558
Colwyn bay, Conway,30269,953
Dover, Kent,34087,861
Falmouth, Cornwall,21635,543
Great Yarmouth, Norfolk,58032,1467
Hastings, East Sussex,85828,1998
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I think you are trying to create a collection of TownType objects, but that isn't what you are doing. The LOF function is returning the length of the file in bytes and dividing length of the object which has nothing to do with the number of records in the file.

Comment: In the end I want to display the contents of the csv file in a table format on the console and be able to edit them, add new records and delete records, but first I want the program to calculate the number of records in the file by dividing total number of bytes in the file by the number of bytes in one record but that is not giving the correct answer.

Comment: So how would I get the program to calculate the number of records in the file?

Comment: See answer below how to read this file into a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the contents into a collection and you can get the number of records from the collection.

```
    Sub Main()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim NumberOfRecords As Integer
    FileName = "N:\2_7_towns(2).csv"

    'read the lines into an array
    Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileName)

    'read the array into a collection of town types
    'this could also be done i a loop if you need better
    'parsing or error handling
    Dim TownList = From line In lines _
        Let data = line.Split(",") _
            Select New With {.Name = data(0), _
                             .County = data(1), _
                             .Population = data(2), _
                             .Area = data(3)}

    NumberOfRecords = TownList.Count
    Console.WriteLine(NumberOfRecords)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Writing to the console would be accomplished with something like:

```
For Each town In TownList
    Console.WriteLine(town.Name + "," + town.County)
Next
```

Comment: Can you explain the code from 'Dim TownList' To '.Area = data(3)' please

Comment: Most importantly the select new with part

Comment: Sure - This is a LINQ query on the lines array it is saying for each line in lines split the data on a comma. Then Select each new line into an object with the properties Name, County etc. then add the object to TownList.

Comment: So what would be the easy way of outputting the townlist on the console as a table, becuase I have tried using FileGet(1, TownList) but I am getting an error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a table, but see the edited answer above of how to loop through collection and write to console.

Comment: Ok, so I got it to display the table in the console, but what actually is a LINQ query, and how come in the select new with statement you have to write .Name, rather than Town.Name?

Comment: LINQ is Language-Integrated Query for .NET with it you can query objects, XML, databases - see this article on MSDN for a full explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx. In the LINQ query you only use .Name because it is the property for the "New" object being created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65422/discussion-between-todd432-and-kevin).

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do that
Test this:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    dim FileName as string = "N:\2_7_towns(2).csv"
    Dim Str() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    'Str(0) contains : "Town, County,Pop, Area"
    'Str(1) contains : "Berwick-upon-tweed, Nothumberland,12870,468"
    'Str(2) contains : "Bideford, devon,16262,430"
    ' etc...

    'Sample code for string searching :
    Dim Lst As New List(Of String)
    Lst.Add(Str(0))
    Dim LookingFor As String = "th"
    For Each Line As String In Str
        If Line.Contains(LookingFor) Then Lst.Add(Line)
    Next
    Dim Result As String = ""
    For Each St As String In Lst
        Result &= St & Environment.NewLine
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(Result)

    'Sample code creating a grid :
    Dim Grid = New DataGridView
    Me.Controls.Add(Grid)
    Grid.ColumnCount = Str(0).Split(","c).GetUpperBound(0) + 1
    Grid.RowCount = Lst.Count - 1
    Grid.RowHeadersVisible = False

    For r As Integer = 0 To Lst.Count - 1
        If r = 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To Lst(r).Split(","c).GetUpperBound(0)
                Grid.Columns(i).HeaderCell.Value = Lst(0).Split(","c)(i)
            Next
        Else
            For i As Integer = 0 To Lst(r).Split(","c).GetUpperBound(0)
                Grid(i, r - 1).Value = Lst(r).Split(","c)(i)
            Next
        End If

    Next
    Grid.AutoResizeColumns()
    Grid.AutoSize = True
End Sub
```